# Importing multiple selected files, properly spliced, into multiple sheets via VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, import

First time I ask a question here, but so far answers from this forum have always helped me a lot. However, now I have been dealing with a problem for weeks and unfortunately never found sufficient answers.
The current task is to update an already existing macro regarding data processing and display to a newer UI and increased usability. However, in the same sense I would like to improve the speed of the macro.
My current problem is opening, loading, splitting and pasting multiple selected .txt files into appropriately named sheets. The files can very quickly have over a hundred thousand entries of data, all separated by either space or enter. For importing and splitting a single file, I stumbled across this code, which I have subsequently adapted for my circumstances:

```vb
Private Sub testModule1()
    Dim arr, tmp, output
    Dim Datei
    Dim FSO
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim str_string, filePath As String
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename
    
    Set Datei = FSO.OpentextFile(filePath)
    str_string = Datei.readall
    Datei.Close
    
    arr = Split(str_string, vbCrLf)
    ReDim output(UBound(arr), 50)
    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        tmp = Split(arr(x), " ")
        For y = 0 To UBound(tmp)
            output(x, y) = tmp(y)
        Next
    Next
      
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output) + 1, UBound(output, 2)) = output
       
End Sub
```

This part lets me select a single file, splits the cells as desired, and finally posts it to the first sheet.

For importing multiple files and naming the sheet after the file name, I found code here (the first solution):
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/importing-multiple-text-files-in-to-multiple-work-sheets-with-text-file-names.1147363/

However, it currently opens in a new workbook, Windows tells me several times that data is overwritten when I do this, and the delimiter is also limited to only one character.

I am currently failing to find a reasonable combination of these two actions. The direct opening and reasonable splitting of several selected files and the subsequent integrating into several sheets named accordingly by file name.
In the old version of the macro, all file paths were first retrieved and stored in cells for this purpose, and later looped through these cells while reading and integrating the individual data in the process. However, everything in a sheet and rather, as I find, cumbersome.

I hope to find a more elegant solution for this problem than having to store data in sheets during editing and I am also happy about other suggestions and solutions.

**EDIT:**

After the hint from Solar Mike I was able to adapt the code to this:

```vb
Private Sub testModule2()
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim fPath As Variant
    Dim FSO
    Dim Datei
    Dim arr, tmp, output
    Dim file, fileName As String
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Please select files to import"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "VBO Files", "*.vbo"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            For Each fPath In .SelectedItems
                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
                fileName = FSO.GetFilename(fPath)
                Set Datei = FSO.OpentextFile(fPath)
                file = Datei.readall
                Datei.Close
                
                
                arr = Split(file, vbCrLf)
                ReDim output(UBound(arr), 50)
                For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    tmp = Split(arr(x), " ")
                    For y = 0 To UBound(tmp)
                        output(x, y) = tmp(y)
                    Next
                Next
                
                Set newSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
                newSht.Name = fileName
                
                Sheets(fileName).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output) + 1, UBound(output, 2)) = output
            Next
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

This does what is actually required, but just importing only 5 files already takes about a minute. Since on average up to 20 files can/should be imported and the processing of the data still takes place afterwards, this still seems a bit much to me.

It should be noted that the data sets are reduced again during processing, something between 40 and 80% of the data are filtered. Unfortunately I don't have the expertise to do this before, even if this would reduce the loading time.

Comment: Many Q&A exist on here, have a look. This is but one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29519916/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after a bit more trial and error with my edited code, I haven't found a better way to optimize the process, so I'm posting the final code in response to the question.
The reduction of the amount of data is now done by a third party program and speeds up the processing sufficiently.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub fileImporter()
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim fPath As Variant
    Dim FSO
    Dim Data
    Dim arr, tmp, output
    Dim file, fileName As String
    Dim x, y As Integer
    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Please select files to import"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "VBO Files", "*.vbo" 'VBO Files are opened and handled like Text Files
        
        If .Show = True Then
            For Each fPath In .SelectedItems
                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
                fileName = FSO.GetFilename(fPath)
                Set Data = FSO.OpentextFile(fPath)
                file = Data.readall
                Data.Close
                
                
                arr = Split(file, vbCrLf)
                ReDim output(UBound(arr), 50)
                For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    tmp = Split(arr(x), " ")
                    For y = 0 To UBound(tmp)
                        output(x, y) = tmp(y)
                    Next
                Next
                
                Set newSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
                newSht.Name = fileName
                
                Sheets(fileName).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output) + 1, UBound(output, 2)) = output
            Next
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Thanks for all the help and I hope this can help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
'updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xDelimiter = "|"
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        With xWb
            xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=xDelimiter
        End With
    Loop
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Kutools for Excel"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: This is almost the code I provided as a link in my question, unfortunately it does not work according to my requirements. Also customizing did not have the desired success.

Comment: The code worked totally fine for me. You can hit the F8 key over and over, to step through the code, and see where the problem is. Or, try a different approach. There are many ways to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: It does work, just not exactly, after tweaking, how I want it to.  However, in combination with my edited code and external software, I have now been able to drastically reduce the processing time. Unfortunately, this has been impossible to implement in VBA only, without loading the complete data.